# Linq - How to combine reflection with where and contains

Tags: c#, linq, reflection, .net-core

I want to create a dynamic method for selecting data by using `contains` in a `where` clause. I found a lot of information about expressions, but I can't find a combination that works.

I posted my method and I'm stuck at this line by searching a solution with refelection or something like that:

> .Where(p => p.Description != null && p.Description.ToLower().Contains(lowerFilter));

What is best practice by solving the problem?

Selection Method:

```
public List<TEntity> GetItems(string sortBy, string sort, string? filter)
{
    IQueryable<TEntity> items = dbContext.Set<TEntity>();

    if (filter != null && filter.Length > 0)
    {
        string lowerFilter = filter.ToLower(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);

        items = items
            .Where(p => p.Description != null && p.Description.ToLower().Contains(lowerFilter));
    }

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sortBy))
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sort))
        {
            items = items.AsQueryable().OrderBy($"{sortBy} {sort}");
        }
    }

    List<TEntity> itemsList = items.ToList();

    return itemsList;
}
```

Comment: I am sorry but kind of confused here. Your method GetItems is generic method. Are you sure that every TEntity has Description column? Or that is what you are trying address here?

Comment: I'm looking for a replacement for the line, because it doesn't work that way because the method is generic. The name of the column can then be specified dynamically as a string.

Comment: I just want to share my thought here. Even though you figure out a way to achieve this via reflection or via EF conventions or some other method, I think, your GetItems method will become messy because, either your code will have multiple if-else statements or where clause becomes heavier. Not sure your use case here but re-visit it once before pursuing in this direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with using dynamic [Expression Builder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/expression-trees/how-to-use-expression-trees-to-build-dynamic-queries):

This generic extension method helps you implement `Contains` for all `IQueryable`:

```
public static IQueryable<T> ContainsByField<T>(this IQueryable<T> q, string field, string value)
{
    var eParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "e");
    var method = field.GetType().GetMethod("Contains");
    var call = Expression.Call(Expression.Property(eParam, field), method, Expression.Constant(value.ToLower()));
    var lambdaExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(
        Expression.AndAlso(
            Expression.NotEqual(Expression.Property(eParam, field), Expression.Constant(null)),
            call
        ),
        eParam
    );

    return q.Where(lambdaExpression);
}
```

Then you need to call as simple like this:

```
items = items.ContainsByField("Description", lowerFilter);
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. I just had to change the line with the `GetMethod` to `typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains", new[] { typeof(string) })` because I got the error "Ambiguous match found" there.
I only have a strange behaviour during my tests. It works correctly with the integrationtests with the real MSSQL-DB. When unit testing against an InMemoryDatabase the value "Test1" is not found.

Comment: Please accept answer as a accepted if it helped to you. I tested this code it works just for this purpose, i think you had other problem which is not relevant to this problem.  Because my code does not have`Test1` etc. It's hard to understand problem from what you said.

Comment: I have found the reason for the different behaviour. In the expression of you, the `.ToLower()` is missing in `.Description.ToLower().Contains(...)`. So it only works with a case insensitive database.  Maybe you can adapt your code? I haven't been able to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Your linq query should work just fine.

```
.Where(p => p.Description != null && p.Description.ToLower().Contains(lowerFilter));
```

In terms of best practice, the only thing I can see for now is the unnecessary nested `if` statement. Which you can simplify as:

```
 if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sortBy) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(sort))
    {
        items = items.AsQueryable().OrderBy($"{sortBy} {sort}");
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately not because I work with a type and Description is not known. I am looking for a solution to replace this line with Reflection or something like that.